# fill input text according to select option using sql and ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

**This is my ajax code :**

```
    $('#nomSalarie').change(function(){
        var req=$('#nomSalarie').attr("value");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "index-ep-fiche.php?nomSalarie="+req,
            dataType : "html",
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
            },
            success:function(data){
                //préremplir tout les inputs de type text
                $('input[name=posteSalarie]').val($('input:hidden[name=posteSalarie]').val());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**This is my PHP code :**

```
$displayForm = $bdd->prepare('SELECT user_poste FROM USER INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  INNER JOIN POSTE ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id WHERE nomSalarie = :nomSalarie ORDER BY user_nom ASC');
$displayForm->bindParam(':nomSalarie', $_GET['nomSalarie']);
```

An user click an option in the select and then if it's clicked i need to display my input text.

**This is my HTML code :**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="formEtape1" id="formEtape2" method="post">
 <select class="form-control" name="nomSalarie" id="nomSalarie">
     <?php while($ligne = $displaySalarie->fetch()){?>
         <option value="<?php echo $ligne['user_id'];?>"><?php echo $ligne['user_nom'].' '.$ligne['user_prenom'];?></option>
     <?php } ?>
 </select>
<?php if(isset($_GET['nomSalarie'])){ 
          $resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch();
          foreach ($resDisplayForm as $key => $value) {
              echo '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
          }     
?>
</form>`
```

I hope you will help me.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: When i select on option the input text doesn't appear

Comment: Did your page gets reloaded?

Comment: no it did not gets reloaded